# change .net framework after create new project

Tags: visual-studio

I've written a program with Visual Studio 2012 and .Net Framework 4.5.
Now I want to change the .Net Framework to .Net Framework 4.
How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project, choose Properties.

Under "Application" you have a dropdown called TargetFramework. Change that to 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse button click on project within *Solution Explorer*. There is *TargetFramework* dropdown on *Application* tab.